# How to enter text into a react-selectize-control using Watir

Tags: watir, watir-classic

I have the following code on the page:

```
 <div class="col-md-5 col-lg-3">
  <div class="react-selectize bootstrap3 root-node simple-select open">
   <div class="react-selectize-control">
    <div class="react-selectize-placeholder">testing!</div>
     <div class="react-selectize-search-field-and-selected-values">
      <input class="resizable-input" style="width: 4px;" type="input">
```

If I physically select the input field and then run the following using watir-classic:

```
BROWSER.div(:class => 'col-md-5 col-lg-3')
       .div(:class => 'react-selectize-search-field-and-selected-values')
       .text_field(:class => 'resizable-input')
       .send_keys('Magg')
```

it will enter `Magg` into the field, but if I don't manually select the field I can't seem to get watir to enter the text.

I've tried the following:

```
BROWSER.div(:class => 'col-md-5 col-lg-3')
       .div(:class => 'react-selectize-search-field-and-selected-values')
       .text_field(:class => 'resizable-input')
```

with

```
.set('Magg')
.fire_event('onfocus')
.fire_event('mousedown')
.fire_event('mouseup')
```

using

```
.parent.text_field(:class => 'resizable-input')
.parent.input(:class => 'resizable-input').set('Magg')
.input(:class => 'resizable-input').set('Magg')
.input(:class => 'resizable-input').send_keys('Magg')
```

I've been working with the developer using the control and neither of us can figure out how to give the control focus so that the `send_keys` works without manually selecting the control. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: does the input have to be clicked on to be active?  does something simple like `b.input(class: "resizable-input").set "foo"` work at all?  (if not, what error do you get if any).  Do you need to specify the outer container to select the input?  e.g. does `puts b.inputs(class: "resizable-input").size` return a value other than 1 ?

Comment: Thanks Chuck
The input may not need to be clicked to be active but I seem to be having issues trying to activate it through Watir. 
Yes, the size returns a value of 2 
When I use .set('Magg')'
I get:
NoMethodError: undefined method `set' for #<Watir::Input:0x3738348>
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-4.3.0/lib/watir-classic/element.rb:314:in `method_missing'
        from (irb):553
        from C:/Ruby193/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
But when I use .send_keys('Magg') I get => 1

Comment: Are there multiple React-Selectize libraries/controls? The [one example](http://furqanzafar.github.io/react-selectize/#/?category=simple&example=editable-value) that I tried worked fine with `send_keys`.

Comment: Thanks @JustinKo, are you using Watir WebDriver or Classic? I'm guessing I may have to figure out how to get WebDriver to work and then try it again.

Comment: @TomFeodoroff, I was using Watir-Classic (with IE11).

Comment: @JustinKo, on Win 10 Pro OS?

Comment: @TomFeodoroff, I used Win 10 Home and Win 7 Pro. Did you try testing against the example page I had previously linked to?

Comment: The size of 2 means there are at least two inputs on the page with that class.. so be sure your code is selecting the right one.  (unless you provide other criteria to make it unique, the default is the code will use the first matching element it finds..     based on http://www.rubydoc.info/github/watir/watir-classic/Watir/InputElement, it looks like watir-classic does not implement the `.set` method for the generic input element (it's defined for subtypes like textfield)  if it had a proper 'type' value, then set would likely work..

Comment: Thanks @JustinKo, sorry yes, I looked at your link, but I'm not an expert programmer and didn't see a solution that made sense to me.

Comment: Thanks @ChuckvanderLinden, by identifying the previous div to the control I was able to hit the one I needed to.

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback folks. I took the time to get WebDriver to work and was successful in getting send_keys to enter the text. Now it's on to my next road block :)

Answer (score 1):

First - obligatory warning that Watir Classic is deprecated and you should be using Watir WebDriver. (which may fix this issue)

Second - technically: `div(:class => 'col-md-5 col-lg-3')` should be `div(:css => '.col-md-5.col-lg-3')` since class should be singular.

Have you tried just doing `element.fire_event(:click)` before `element.set`?

Comment: Thanks for you feedback @titusfortner. I had problems getting WebDriver to work so I just used classic to show my coworkers the wonders of Watir and what it can do. Kinda fell flat on my face when I couldn't enter text into a field :( Yes, sorry, I should have included the .fire_event('click') as one of the options we tried, but alas, it did not work either.

Comment: So I got WebDriver working now and my co-workers are far more impressed now that I got this working :)

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that your HTML has an invalid 'type' value for the input tag.   Per [W3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.html) the type of 'input' is not a valid type choice for an input tag.

That is likely what is causing the method you expect to work (such as `.set`) to fail.  It also means that all the watir methods to return the more specific sub-types of input (e.g. `.text_field`) will not work to select that tag.

Watir defines the specific input related methods (such as .set, .unset) according to the specific sub-type of input tag, and has methods to select those specific input types (such as `.button`). Normally you'd select an input tag using the method for it's sub-type, but because that value is not valid, that is not an option in this case, and you are forced to use `.input`.  But as we just discussed, the input object in watir does not have methods like .set defined.  So your only fallback is to use .sendkeys to send keystrokes to the element.

If it was me I'd write up a bug on that HTML, that it is not using a proper value for 'type' per the W3 spec.

Fixing the HTML to be valid will likely cause it to work far better with Watir or any other automation tool, especially those based on webdriver.

Comment: Great advice, thanks @ChuckvanderLinden. I'll also be asking the dev to add id's to controls so I don't need to reference the divs around them to make sure I get the right one :)